# Feedback on my game?

Tags: queens-gambit-accepted

```
[FEN ""]
[Title "Bskg vs NN"]
[Result "1-0"]

1.d4 d5 2.c4 dxc4 3.e3 Nc6 { A mistake, blocks counterplay based on c7-c5 } 4.Bxc4 { Seems passive and the light squared bishop is locked in. However, e7-e5 is difficult with the knight on c6 in view of d4-d5 } 4...e6 5.Nf3 Bd6 6.Nc3 Nf6 7.O-O O-O 8.e4 { Is this move good? It was the only plan I found } 8...e5 9.dxe5 { I thought I would have an advantage in the following endgame due to my central pawn, but I now like d5 better as it seems more ambitious } 9...Nxe5 10.Nxe5 Bxe5 11.Qxd8 Rxd8 12.Bg5 { I think the simplification was a bad idea for white, black's d-rook and dark square bishop are very strong. } 12...b6 13.Bd5 Rb8 14.Rfd1 { Trying to take the initiative with tactical threats and taking the open file } 14...Rf8 15.h3 h6 { Isn't Ba6 better? } 16.Be3 Bb7 { nxd5 was a bit scary and Ba6 would be good, but after the move that was played I think white is better again. The rook is bad on b7 and white gains time } 17.Bxb7 Rxb7 18.Bd4 { bxd4 activates white's rooks and Re8 is strongly met by f4 } 18...Re8 19.Bxe5 Rxe5 20.f4 Rc5 21.e5 { The knight must move to a terrible square } 21...Nh5 { Here the knight will be lost } 22.Rd4 Rb8 23.g4 Nxf4 24.Rxf4 Rxe5 25.Rd1 c6 26.Rd7 a5 27.Rfxf7 Rg5 28.Ne4 Rg6 29.Kg2 h5 30.Kf3 hxg4 31.hxg4 Kh7 32.Ng3 Rg8 33.Nf5 Kh8 34.Ne7 
1-0
```

I had white.

Answer (score 1):

A good game between equally matched players.

`3. e4` is more common and is one of the points of the gambit - you gain more space. You're going to use an extra move to get it to `e4` on move 8. Might as well do it on move 3.

`9. dxe5` allows a series of trades that sucks the life out of the game. I think `9. d5` is slightly stronger and is what I expected you to play.

`14...Rf8` made my face hurt. Instead, consider `Ba6` or `Be6`. The latter allows an isolated e pawn but it connects the rooks and removes White's best piece.

`15...h6` I'd have `Nxd5` to kill that good Bishop. That would be add sense to the `Rf8` move.

After `16. Bb7`, followed by `... c5`, Black's Rook is not so badly placed and is closer to making a battery.

`21... Nh5` A Knight on the rim is dim.

`26. Rd7` is a strong move. Note this would not have been possible had Black not wasted a move with `22... Rb8` but instead simply pushed the `c` pawn per a previous comment.  That is, consider `18... Bxd4 19. Rd4 c5 20. Rd2 Re8`.  White may be better, but there's no obvious win here.

The game didn't do a lot for me as the trades removed most of the tension. Had Black not blundered the Knight it was looking drawish though I did prefer White's more active Rooks.

Comment: `3.e3` is one of the standard moves here, and even slightly more popular than `3.e4` in my database. Anyway, both are well-accepted approaches.

Comment: I agree that 9. d5 would have been better.  With 3...Nc6 combined with 9. d5, Black would be lacking a half-open file, which might become uncomfortable unless s/he could work in ...f5 or ...c5.  Like @ETD, I don't agree that 3. e4 was necessarily better.  It's easy to go astray with the kind of unstable center that creates.